# Routing for API in area MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, api, area

I have issue for Routing API in Area in ASP.Net MVC. I added many area for (Admin,Guest,SuperAdmin) , I want add API for each user, but I can't access to API.

```
     // added this code in Admin Area
            public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context) 
            {
                context.MapRoute(
                    "Admin_default",
                    "Admin/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                    new { action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
                );
            }

    // added this code in SuperAdmin Area
       public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context) 
            {
            context.MapRoute(
                    "SuperAdmin_default",
                    "SuperAdmin/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                    );
            }

    }
```

but I want use code as API  , So Add

```
public static class WebApiConfig
    {
        public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

            config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.Add(new MediaTypeHeaderValue("text/html"));

            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                "DefaultApi",
                "api/{controller}/{id}",
                new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );

            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                "CustomApi",
                "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );


            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute("SuperAdminDefaultApiGet", "Api/superadmin/{controller}", new { action = "Get" }, new { httpMethod = new HttpMethodConstraint(HttpMethod.Get) });


            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute("DefaultApiGet", "Api/{controller}", new { action = "Get" }, new { httpMethod = new HttpMethodConstraint(HttpMethod.Get) });
            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute("DefaultApiPost", "Api/{controller}", new { action = "Post" }, new { httpMethod = new HttpMethodConstraint(HttpMethod.Post) });
        }
}
```

I add Two Controller with same Name in SuperAdmin , Admin

```
    [RoutePrefix("api/superAdmin/users")]
        public class SuperAdminController : ApiController
        {
            [Route("getUser")]
            [AllowAnonymous]
            public HttpResponseMessage getUser()
            {
            // code
            }
        }

    [RoutePrefix("api/admin/users")]
    public class AdminController : ApiController
    {
        [Route("getUser")]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        public HttpResponseMessage getUser()
        {
        // code
        }
    }
```

Can anyone help me how I can solve the routing, or support me with article for routing API in Area MVC

Answer (score 0):

Add this code in your webapi.config at the top before any api route get registered

```
config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
```

Also try comment this lines temporary while testing

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute("SuperAdminDefaultApiGet", "Api/superadmin/{controller}", new { action = "Get" }, new { httpMethod = new HttpMethodConstraint(HttpMethod.Get) });


        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute("DefaultApiGet", "Api/{controller}", new { action = "Get" }, new { httpMethod = new HttpMethodConstraint(HttpMethod.Get) });
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute("DefaultApiPost", "Api/{controller}", new { action = "Post" }, new { httpMethod = new HttpMethodConstraint(HttpMethod.Post) });
```